# Changing colour of cells when values update in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

Is there a possible way to change the background colour of cells if they update using a macro?

I'm using a VBA for loop with IF statements that are updating the cells.

Is it possible to change the background colour within the for loop/after they've updated?

```
Dim cella As Range
For Each cella In Range("D15:AE15").Cells
If cella.Value = 0 And cella.Offset(17).Value = 2 Then
    cella.Value = 1
    cella.Offset(17).Value = 1
    cella.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
End If
Next cella
```

I've tried using the interior colour index function within the loop but it doesn't seem to work? (And I only want to colour the cells that update)

Comment: Why not simply record the change while doing it manually? Should show you how it works...

Comment: What is wrong with your code? It is supposed to change the colour of your cella to red. Doesn't it do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is something like:

```
        With cella.Interior
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = 255
        End With
```

However, there are some syntax errors in your code. I made some assumptions based on what I saw but this is more correct altogether:

```
    For Each cella In Range("A1:B15")
       If cella.Value = 0 And cella.Offset(17, 0).Value = 2 Then

          cella.Value = 1
          cella.Offset(17, 0).Value = 1 'offset syntax is (rows, columns)

          With cella.Interior
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = 255
          End With

       End If
    Next cella
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert a `Worksheet_change` in the code module for e.g. Sheet1

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   <your code>
End sub
```

`Target` is the changed range (cell)